# How to provide file path of JSON file kept in azure devops git repository to PowerShell script.Getting file not found exception

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-rm-template

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hADNE.png)Im trying to run this PowerShell script through azure release pipeline.
Azure provides json file and PowerShell script to deploy a linked service or dataset of data factory. But the path of the json file is assumed is of local computer. But while executing the same through azure Devops release pipeline, how to provide the json file path in PowerShell script and execute the Devops release pipeline.

Powershell script -

Set-AzDataFactoryV2LinkedService -DataFactoryName "DemoADF" `-ResourceGroupName "DemoRG" -Name "AzureStorageLinkedService"`
-DefinitionFile "./LinkedService.json"

LinkedService.json file -

{
"name": "AzureStorageLinkedService",
"properties": {
"type": "AzureStorage",
"typeProperties": {
"connectionString": "ConnectionStringDetails"
},
"connectVia": {
"referenceName": "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime",
"type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
}
}
}

Tried using - $env:(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/LinkedService.json but not working

Azure DevOps Release pipeline error -

```
2020-07-28T04:23:31.1358415Z ##[debug]Error record:
2020-07-28T04:23:31.2243264Z ##[debug]Set-AzDataFactoryV2LinkedService : ./LinkedService.json
2020-07-28T04:23:31.2263866Z ##[debug]At D:\a\r1\a\LS_adf\ykfactory\AllADFDeploymentTasks\LinkedService.ps1:1 char:1
2020-07-28T04:23:31.2280510Z ##[debug]+ Set-AzDataFactoryV2LinkedService -DataFactoryName "DataFlowADFVNet" `
2020-07-28T04:23:31.2312596Z ##[debug]+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2020-07-28T04:23:31.2342558Z ##[debug]    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzDataFactoryV2LinkedService], FileNotFoundException
2020-07-28T04:23:31.2361626Z ##[debug]    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.DataFactoryV2.SetAzureDataFactoryLinkedServiceCommand
2020-07-28T04:23:31.2379154Z ##[debug] 
2020-07-28T04:23:31.2415190Z ##[debug]Script stack trace:
2020-07-28T04:23:31.2479403Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, D:\a\r1\a\LS_adf\ykfactory\AllADFDeploymentTasks\LinkedService.ps1: line 1
2020-07-28T04:23:31.2532900Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, D:\a\_temp\a652e51d-54ce-438d-b59a-d8b118516fe9.ps1: line 41
2020-07-28T04:23:31.2553826Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
2020-07-28T04:23:31.2594489Z ##[debug]Exception:
**2020-07-28T04:23:31.2681432Z ##[debug]S*ystem.IO.**FileNotFoundException**: ./LinkedService.json***
2020-07-28T04:23:31.2716695Z ##[debug]   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.DataFactoryV2.DataFactoryClient.ReadJsonFileContent(String path)
2020-07-28T04:23:31.2740090Z ##[debug]   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.DataFactoryV2.SetAzureDataFactoryLinkedServiceCommand.ExecuteCmdlet()
2020-07-28T04:23:31.2760357Z ##[debug]   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.AzurePSCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
2020-07-28T04:23:31.3196351Z ##[error]./LinkedService.json
2020-07-28T04:23:31.3212488Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error]./LinkedService.json
2020-07-28T04:23:32.1091196Z ##[debug]Exit code: 1
2020-07-28T04:23:32.1091982Z ##[debug]Leaving Invoke-VstsTool.
2020-07-28T04:23:32.1093065Z ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
2020-07-28T04:23:32.1094438Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
2020-07-28T04:23:32.1106224Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed]Error detected
2020-07-28T04:23:32.1107726Z ##[debug]Loading module from path 'D:\a\_tasks\AzurePowerShell_72a1931b-effb-4d2e-8fd8-f8472a07cb62\5.173.0\ps_modules\VstsAzureHelpers_\VstsAzureHelpers_.psm1'.
2020-07-28T04:23:32.1108852Z ##[debug]$OVER[enter image description here][1]
```

Latest Error -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rvzao.png)
2020-07-28T14:12:59.1777082Z ##[debug]Error record:
2020-07-28T14:12:59.2606789Z ##[debug]Set-AzDataFactoryV2LinkedService : D:\a\r1\a\LinkedService.json
2020-07-28T14:12:59.2614645Z ##[debug]At D:\a\r1\a\LS_adf\ykfactory\AllADFDeploymentTasks\LinkedService.ps1:7 char:1
2020-07-28T14:12:59.2641183Z ##[debug]+ Set-AzDataFactoryV2LinkedService -DataFactoryName "DataFlowADFVNet" `
2020-07-28T14:12:59.2665039Z ##[debug]+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2020-07-28T14:12:59.2686771Z ##[debug]    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzDataFactoryV2LinkedService], FileNotFoundException
2020-07-28T14:12:59.2731339Z ##[debug]    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.DataFactoryV2.SetAzureDataFactoryLinkedServiceCommand
2020-07-28T14:12:59.2746815Z ##[debug]
2020-07-28T14:12:59.2791357Z ##[debug]Script stack trace:
2020-07-28T14:12:59.2841187Z ##[debug]at , D:\a\r1\a\LS_adf\ykfactory\AllADFDeploymentTasks\LinkedService.ps1: line 7
2020-07-28T14:12:59.2894685Z ##[debug]at , D:\a_temp\773f2897-4445-4797-b8c4-62e1fbc3c46a.ps1: line 41
2020-07-28T14:12:59.2915479Z ##[debug]at , : line 1
2020-07-28T14:12:59.2931046Z ##[debug]Exception:
2020-07-28T14:12:59.3013273Z ##[debug]System.IO.FileNotFoundException: D:\a\r1\a\LinkedService.json
2020-07-28T14:12:59.3039882Z ##[debug]   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.DataFactoryV2.DataFactoryClient.ReadJsonFileContent(String path)
2020-07-28T14:12:59.3062765Z ##[debug]   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.DataFactoryV2.SetAzureDataFactoryLinkedServiceCommand.ExecuteCmdlet()
2020-07-28T14:12:59.3082130Z ##[debug]   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.AzurePSCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
2020-07-28T14:12:59.3469116Z ##[error]D:\a\r1\a\LinkedService.json
2020-07-28T14:12:59.3489081Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error]D:\a\r1\a\LinkedService.json
2020-07-28T14:12:59.4029653Z ##[debug]Exit code: 1
2020-07-28T14:12:59.4104968Z ##[debug]Leaving Invoke-VstsTool.
2020-07-28T14:12:59.4476571Z ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
2020-07-28T14:12:59.4477979Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
2020-07-28T14:12:59.4575374Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed]Error detected
2020-07-28T14:12:59.4603727Z ##[debug]Loading module from path 'D:\a_tasks\AzurePowerShell_72a1931b-effb-4d2e-8fd8-f8472a07cb62\5.173.0\ps_modules\VstsAzureHelpers_\VstsAzureHelpers_.psm1'.
2020-07-28T14:12:59.4744776Z ##[debug]$OVERRIDING $global:DebugPreference from 'Continue' to 'SilentlyContinue'.
2020-07-28T14:12:59.4926089Z ##[debug]Loading resource strings from: D:\a_tasks\AzurePowerShell_72a1931b-effb-4d2e-8fd8-f8472a07cb62\5.173.0\ps_modules\VstsAzureHelpers_/module.json
2020-07-28T14:12:59.5854494Z ##[debug]Loaded 13 strings.

Comment: You mean you need to provide the path of the json file to powershell, but the json file exists on the local compture? So what does your local compture refer to? Your local computer or the agent you execute the pipeline? You need to provide the relationship between the local compture and the agent so that we can know what kind of path to provide

Comment: Hi Leo, Added more details and error message of Azure DdevOps pipeline. My Powershell script and JSON file both are in Azure Git Repo in same folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to provide file path of JSON file kept in azure devops git repository to PowerShell script.Getting file not found exception

We could not use the predefined variables in the powershell scripts directly.

To use predefined variables with powershell, we could use the [inline powershell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops) or we could pass the value of predefined variables through PowerShell parameters:

```
-pass $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
```

[image]

And my test.ps1:

```
Param(
 [String]$pass
)

Write-Host "$pass"
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: thank you Leo. But still getting the error. I'm not sure where its going wrong. I tried this one - -pass $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory/LinkedService.Json) and -pass $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)  -DefinitionFile $pass"\LinkedService.json" (filepath tried like this way) in both the cases still getting the error file not found exception. added the new error in the Question and new error image.

Comment: Thank You Leo. Now it finally worked after passing full path of the JSON file like - $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ArtifactAlias/FolderPathinGitRepo/LinkedService.Json. so the final solution is to add this full path as a parameter.

Comment: @YogeshKulkarni, Glad to know that resolved your question :). Have a nice day!